# Regex Remove white spaces from a group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Hi I have the following values

```
000001010016C02AB  111*
000001010016C02    111H
000001010016C      111
```

And the expected output is

```
00000101001,C02AB,*
00000101001,C02,H
00000101001,C,
```

The values might vary.The length of this string will always be 23.if a character is not present then the position will be a filled with a white space. The Regex now i have is

```
(^.{11})[0-9](.{5})(?:.{5})(.*)
```

But while using this Regex in the second group there are white spaces returned. I want those those white spaces to be removed.

Current Output:

```
00000101001,C02AB,*
00000101001,C02  ,H
00000101001,C    ,
```

Could anyone help me remove the white spaces from the second group?

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vjucI9/2/)

Comment: What is your regex flavor (language you are using)?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Java

Answer (score 2):

- Find: `^(.{11})\d(\S+)\s*.{3}(.?)$`
- Replace: `$1,$2,$3`

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of string
  (.{11})   : 11 any character, stored in group 1
  \d        : 1 digit
  (\S+)     : 1 or more non spaces, stored in group 2
  \s*       : 0 or more spaces
  .{3}      : 3 any character
  (.?)      : 0 or 1 character, stored in group 3
$
```

**Result:**

```
00000101001,C02AB,*
00000101001,C02,H
00000101001,C,
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you may implement a custom replacement logic using [`Matcher#appendReplacement()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) and just `trim()` the `matcher.group(2)` value:

```
String strs[]  = {"000001010016C02AB  111*", "000001010016C02    111H", "000001010016C      111 ", "901509010012V      154 "};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.{11})[0-9](.{5}).{5}(.*)");
for (String s: strs) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
            m.appendReplacement(result, m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2).trim()  + "," + m.group(3));
    }
    System.out.println(result.toString());
}
```

Result:

```
00000101001,C02AB,*
00000101001,C02,H
00000101001,C, 
90150901001,V,
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/TV49Km).

Note I removed `^` because `Matcher#matches()` method requires a full string match. Use the `Pattern.DOTALL` option if the string may contain line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

In Regex there are capturing groups, just concatenate these 2 groups and you'll have your results, in the concatenation you may insert a comma

```
 ^(\w+)\s*\d+(\D+)$
```

A group is what is inside ()

Comment: I am looking for removing the white spaces captured. See sample Here https://regex101.com/r/vjucI9/2

Answer (score 0):

Using the end assertion `$` makes it easy to match:

```
^(.{11})\d(\w+).+(.)$
```